# My device is rooted but my android app does not have root access (libsuperuser)

Tags: android, root, su

I am trying to build an application based on libsuperuser. My device is rooted but I have two problems:

1) After to export my apk, for some reason it is asking for certificate. I need to export signing the app which does not make sense for a rooted device. Why do I need to sign if the device is rooted ?

2) When I run the app, I checked if the app has root privileges calling Shell.SU.available() available in the libsuperuser which returns "false". It means the app is does not root privileges and I cannot run commands like "chmod".

3) If I try to call the shell commands using libsuperuser API adding "su" as prefix in the log message I see that the current app user (which is not root) does not have "su" privileges.

PS: I know Eclipse is deprecated but this project was build on Eclipse and I had some problems importing to Android Studio.. that's why I am using Eclipse at moment.
Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score -1):

Did you add the permission in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
```

Comment: sounds like a mixed up of the compatibility with libsuperuser, which root is is? Koush's or ChainFire?

Comment: it is chainfire. My system is not SELinux and I included libsuperuser as export library in my project. The lib was included as external jar.

Comment: Exporting an app, that is release mode? does require signing with your key.Debug apks do not need it.

Comment: even in debug mode I have the same problem. I do not know what to do.